# HAproxy redirect all HTTP requests from single frontend to single backend (multiple ports)

Tags: proxy, domain, http, haproxy, port

I have haproxy installed and it works just fine, currently I have configuration that looks as follows

```
frontend public_http
        # Listen on port 80
        bind *:80
        mode http
        # Define ACLs for each domain
        acl acl_webtest  hdr(host) -i -f /etc/haproxy/acls/webtest
        use_backend back_web_test if acl_webtest

backend back_web_test
        mode http
        balance roundrobin  # Load Balancing algorithm
        option httpchk
        option forwardfor
        server webtest 192.168.0.123:80 weight 1 maxconn 512 check
```

As you can see I am redirecting incoming HTTP traffic to the backend on the same port (80 default for HTTP).

But my question :
 Is it possible to have single frontnend without bunch of `bind *:<port>` statements and redirect to a single backend to the same `<port>`. BUT only HTTP traffic. I know that default port for HTTP is 80, but we are able to send HTTP request to any port.

It looks like TCP proxy, but I need to redirect to a backend based on domain, and TCP layer (OSI 4) doesn't know anything about domain.

So I hope, I've described my problem clearly.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: You are saying *redirect*, but you almost certainly mean to say *forward*.  When you *redirect*, the proxy sends a `3XX` HTTP response to the browser, along with a `Location:` response header, the browser changes its address bar, and connects to the redirect target.  TCP connections don't redirect.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by omitting the *:port* on the *server* line

```
frontend public_http
    # Listen on port 80 to 1024, included
    bind :80-1024
    # Listen on ports 8088, 8080, 8000
    bind :8088,:8080,:8000
    mode http
    # Define ACLs for each domain
    acl acl_webtest  hdr(host) -i -f /etc/haproxy/acls/webtest
    use_backend back_web_test if acl_webtest

backend back_web_test
    mode http
    balance roundrobin  # Load Balancing algorithm
    option httpchk
    option forwardfor
    server webtest 192.168.0.123 weight 1 port 80 maxconn 512 check
```

With this configuration, the backend connection will be made to the same port the client connected to. The separate port keyword on the server line is used for health checks.